# EF6 and Breeze 1.4.6 (obsolete) not work for hottowel project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, breeze, hottowel

I created an Asp.Net MVC using VS2013 and used nuget to add HotTowel (V2.0.1 of 9/11/2013). I created a couple of ViewModel, Models. However, I got the following error.

It sounds there is an issue with "Breeze Server (obsolete)" and EF6. However, it failed when I tried to install the non-obsolete Breeze for EF6.

Install EF6 version of breeze error.

```
Installing 'Breeze.WebApi2.EF6 1.4.6'.
Successfully installed 'Breeze.WebApi2.EF6 1.4.6'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Updating 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData 4.0.30506' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData 5.0.0' failed. Unable to find a version of 'Breeze.Server.WebApi.Core' that is compatible with 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData 5.0.0'.
```

```
readonly EFContextProvider<ApplicationDbContext> _contextProvider = new EFContextProvider<ApplicationDbContext>();

[HttpGet]
public string Metadata()
{
    return _contextProvider.Metadata(); // Error occurred here.
}
```

```
System.MissingMethodException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233069
  Message=Method not found: 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter.get_ObjectContext()'.
  Source=Breeze.WebApi.EF
  StackTrace:
       at Breeze.WebApi.EF.EFContextProvider`1.GetMetadataFromDbContext(Object context)
       at Breeze.WebApi.EF.EFContextProvider`1.GetMetadataFromContext(Object context)
       at Breeze.WebApi.EF.EFContextProvider`1.BuildJsonMetadata()
       at Breeze.WebApi.ContextProvider.Metadata()
       at ST13a.Controllers.BreezeController.Metadata() in c:\Users\nick\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ST13a\ST13a\Controllers\BreezeController.cs:line 25
       at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the Durandal HotTowel? If so, we (John and I) haven't updated that to cope with the changes that cascaded down with the November VS 2013 release. We're behind. No workaround yet. Stay tuned.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Durandal HotTowel. Do you know when the new version will be out? Or should I switch to HotTowel.Angular? Does HotTowel.Angular support VS 2013 release well? Is there an example code like CCJS-Scratch for HotTowl durandal?

Comment: I love Durandal and am hopeful of getting it back up to VS2013 snuff soon ... before year end.  There are [HotTowel.Angular NuGet packages](http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=HotTowel) for VS2013. Best way to learn about that is from John Papa's Pluralsight course "[Building Apps with Angular and Breeze](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/build-apps-angular-breeze)".